# Doctrine, subquery, Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

When I use named parameters inside a subquery in the select clause, I get this error:

Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Maybe this error will go out if I rewrite the query using the QueryBuilder. But I like to see the DQL statement with my style:

```
$dql = 'SELECT u,
            (SELECT count(e1.id)
               FROM FrontendBundle:Entrega e1
               JOIN e1.usuario u1 
              WHERE u1.id = u.id
                AND e1.programa = :programaId) AS numentregas

          FROM FrontendBundle:Usuario u
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mat FROM FrontendBundle:Matricula mat
                            WHERE mat.centro = :centroId
                            AND mat.usuario = u.id)
         ';

$consulta = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);

$consulta->setParameter('programaId', $programaId);
$consulta->setParameter('centroId', $centroId);
```

I always use this code structure. But in this case, when i use ":programaId" inside the select-subquery, i get the error.

But, surprisely, ":centroId" inside the where-subselect works.

Don't try to analize the complete select, i have cut some not important parts.
Thanks

Comment: That DQL works. Doctrine support subselects in the "select part" and in the "where part". The problem is the setParameter. When the parameter is in the "where exists (select ... :param)" part, the it works. But in the "Select (select ... :param)... FROM..." doesn't works. Anyhow I still use string formating to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a query without using the query builder I suggest using php's built in PDO:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

```
try {
    $sql = 'SELECT u,
            (SELECT count(e1.id)
               FROM FrontendBundle:Entrega e1
               JOIN e1.usuario u1
              WHERE u1.id = u.id
                AND e1.programa = :programaId) AS numentregas
            FROM FrontendBundle:Usuario u
           WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mat FROM FrontendBundle:Matricula mat
                            WHERE mat.centro = :centroId
                            AND mat.usuario = u.id)';

    $sth = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(':programaId', $programaId);
    $sth->bindParam(':centroId', $centroId);

    $sth->execute();

    return $sth->fetchAll();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    return false;
}
```